# Not able to bundle with ruby installed with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I have installed ruby version `1.9.3-p484` using `rbenv`. I installed `rbenv` using `homebrew`. I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I am on OS X El Capitan.

I get the following error when I run `bundle`:

```
Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with
OpenSSL using RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.
```

Comment: How did you install ruby, please share your command

Comment: It was installed using `rbenv install`, but the problem seems to have fixed itself after I did another upgrade to El Capitan.

Comment: I am still facing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall your ruby and try to reinstall it like

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl" rbenv install 1.9.3-p484
```

Or try this

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/opt/local rbenv install 1.9.3-p484
```

Comment: Some link like:
Usage: rbenv install [-f] [-kvp] <version>
       rbenv install [-f] [-kvp] <definition-file>
       rbenv install -l|--list

Comment: Bundle happens fine but I am not able to run rails server. Getting following error: `cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)`

Comment: See if you have SSL at this location /usr/local/opt/openssl or this location /opt/local

Comment: I had checked for the SSL location. I removed and installed ruby back which fixed the issue. Thanks.